# Possible to create project plan that task dates automatically calculate based on final delivery date? Similar to microsoft project

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, ms-project

I have a project plan that exists in Microsoft Project and/or Excel.  In both of those tools, I can put in our target "go live" date at the end of the project, and it then auto calculates all of the proceeding tasks based on assigned durations for those tasks...ultimately telling you a "start" date.  I would like to use Sharepoint instead, so that I can have assigned resources update their tasks on Sharepoint.  I know how to create a timeline/task list in Sharepoint, I just dont know how to or if you can automate the start/end dates based on a final delivery date?  Or, is it possible to take a plan that is in Microsoft project and upload it into a task list?

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint supports calculated fields with syntax that is very similar to Excel. If you have a column with an end date and one or more columns with durations in days, then you can create a calculated column where the total of the duration columns is subtracted from the End date to return the start date.

To keep the calculation as simple as possible, you would need to include weekend days and holidays in the durations, because SharePoint does NOT have the equivalent for Excel's NetWorkDays, which excludes weekends when it calculates durations.

In this screenshot, the calculated column **calcStartDate** has the formula

```
=EndDate-(phase1duration+phase2duration)
```

and is set to display as a date.

[image]